# How to make Python consider multiple repeating elements as only one in the string?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    a = print(input().strip(" ").replace(" ", "..."))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was creating this little program that detects any space IN BETWEEN the words and turn in to only three space, no matter how many space the user typed between words. I tried using re module but it didn't work...

Comment: So given input like `this is a test`, you would like to see `this...is...a...test`?

Comment: if the input is " _____hello________world____" or something similar, my expected output would be like "hello...world."

Comment: You may want to look into the string `split` method, which by default splits a string on whitespace. Combined with the `join` method, you can probably get what you want.

Comment: The space(s) at the beginning and the end of the string should be gone and the space(s) between words should become only three dot (...).

Comment: You might want to look at https://regex101.com/ to help test and debug a regular expression to accomplish this.

Comment: Regex `"( )+"` will detect any no of space, so you can do something like this: `re.sub("( )+", "...",string)`

Comment: "I tried using re module but it didn't work". Please update your question with your attempt at using the `re` module, so that we can help fix or improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated with **@Grismar** comment:
use [.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) with default parameter(`None` or no parameter), then consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator.

Here is the solution using

- `split` the string with no parameter,
- `join` the array with "..."

```
def input():
    return "     hello        world    "
def main():
    a = print("...".join(input().split()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output: `hello...world`

Comment: If you don't filter by individual spaces, but just by whitespace (the default for `.split()`), you don't need the `.filter()`. Also, don't shadow names like `input` with user-defined functions.

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for your comment! I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given there aren't any examples of input and expected output, I had to make an assumption about desired behaviour.

> detects any space IN BETWEEN the words and turn in to only three
> space, no matter how many space the user typed between words.

It sounds like you want to look for any whitespace between words in a string and then massage that to have three spaces?

---

Here's a scrappy solution. It basically takes a string, splits it into individual words. We then create a list of words and adds three spaces after it (the f-string part). We can then can contaneate those new word-parts into a string. Then, finally, we can construct a sentence by joining the elements of words between the periods.

```
my_text = "Hello this is   a test     string with   different amount      of spaces   between  the      words .  Second sentence goes   here ."

# Splits the string based on whitespace
list_of_words = my_text.split()

# List comprehension and f-string 
list_of_words_with_spaces = [f'{word}   ' for word in list_of_words]

new_string = ''
for word in list_of_words_with_spaces:
    new_string += word

final_string = ''
for sentence in new_string.split('.'):
    if not sentence.strip(): # Check to ignore for empty sentences
        break
    final_string += sentence[:-3] + '.' # Remove the whitespace before the period
```

The final string looks like this:

```
'Hello   this   is   a   test   string   with   different   amount   of   spaces   between   the   words.   Second   sentence   goes   here.'
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regular expression operator is the Kleene plus, written as `+`. It will match the preceding character one or more times. Therefore, `' +'` is the regex that will match one or more spaces in a row.

To use this in python:

```
import re

def main():
     a = print(re.sub(r' +', '   ', input().strip(" ")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, a simple loop through the string can work too:

```
a = input().strip()
output = []
for word in a.split(' '):
    if word is not "":
        output.append(word)
print('   '.join(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to get what you need:

```
import re

example = '  hello world   this is  an     example  '

replacement = '...'

print(replacement.join(example.split()))
print(re.sub(r'\s+', replacement, example.strip()))
```

Output:

```
hello...world...this...is...an...example
hello...world...this...is...an...example
```

`split()` without parameters splits over any amount of whitespace, and join takes the resulting iterable and joins the parts together with the `replacement` strings.

The second example shows how to substitute whitespace with the `replacement` strings using regular expressions, but it removes the whitespace on the outside with `.strip()`. The regular expression `\s+` just means "whitespace characters, 1 or more, as many as possible" - which is what you want to replace.